# jQuery boxes slideshow

Tags: jquery, slideshow, fade

I'm looking to develop or use an existing jQuery slideshow.

The characterization of the slide show is as followed

There will be 5 boxes that will use the same image pool and rotate the images on the boxes individually without displaying the same image on 2 or more boxes at the same time.

It will look something like this :

[image]

Each box will display the rotating (fade) images.

How is it possible to achieve this effect? Do you know of any existing plugin that creates it?

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

### *[jsBin demo](http://jsbin.com/ituwid/1/edit)*

Using the **[fademe](http://roxon.in/scripts/fademe_jquery_plugin/)** jQuery plugin:

HTML:

```
<div class="boxes"></div>
```

CSS:

```
.box{
  width:100px;
  height:100px;
  border:4px solid #000;
  margin:5px;
  float:left;
}
.box img{
  position:absolute;
}
```

jQuery:

```
// IMAGES ARRAY:
images = [
  'http://placehold.it/100x100/cf5&text=1',
  'http://placehold.it/100x100/adf&text=2',
  'http://placehold.it/100x100/468&text=3',
  'http://placehold.it/100x100/953&text=4',
  'http://placehold.it/100x100/583&text=5',
  'http://placehold.it/100x100/f27&text=6',
  'http://placehold.it/100x100/48f&text=7'
];

// GENERATE BOXES
for(i=0;i<5;i++){
 $('.boxes').append('<div class="box"/>');
}

// APPEND ALL IMAGES TO EACH BOX
for(i=0;i<images.length;i++){
 $('.box').append('<img src="'+ images[i] +'" />');
}

// APPLY fademe plugin TO EACH BOX
for(i=0;i<5;i++){
 $('.box').eq(i).fademe(0,0,i+1);  // the 3rd value is the 'S' ooption (starting slide number)
}
```

Comment: Awesome ! exactly what i was looking for

Comment: it appears that this plugin got a weird problem on internet explorer 8  - you can see on the plugin page that sometimes some random image just disappears any thoughts why ?

Comment: forget about it , found out i had a trailing comma on the image list ... hopefully internet explorer 8 will go away soon

Answer (score 0):

I would recommend you to have a look at jQuery [SlideJS](http://www.slidesjs.com/) plugin if you have not looked at it.

Check [this](http://www.slidesjs.com/#examples) for different examples

```
<script>
        $(function(){
            $("#slides").slides();
        });
    </script>

<body>
    <div id="slides">
        <div class="slides_container">
            <div>
                <img src="img1">
            </div>
            <div>
                <img src="img2">
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
</body>
```

You can also combine custom options:

```
$(function(){
      $("#slides").slides({
        preload: true,
        preloadImage: '/img/loading.gif',
        play: 5000,
        pause: 2500,
        hoverPause: true
      });
    });
```